# Why does my UDF mark this error when I used it in a query but not when I used it outside of it?

Tags: jquery, sql, google-bigquery, subquery, user-defined-functions

I made a query to have a column of "Prof" and it works perfectly but when I made an UDF with same data it gives me this error
Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.

This is the query I use to call the function

```
`SELECT `pf.ObtieneProf`(CAST(c_s_o_d_n AS INT64), CAST (c_s_o_n AS INT64), CAST(c_s_n AS INT64), CAST(cn AS INT64)) AS PROF
FROM `pf.con``
```

THE UDF is the next one:

```
`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `iaa.pf.ObtieneProf`(division INT64, operadora INT64, sucursal      INT64, contrato INT64) RETURNS STRING AS (
(
(
      SELECT NOMTER AS NOMBRE

FROM `pf.c_v` CV, 
`pf.ter` TER, 
`pf.j_c` JCO

WHERE CV.cv_ter_numid = TER.numid
  AND CV.cv_secuencia = JCO.JCO_CV_SECUENCIA 
  AND CV.cv_ter_numid = TER.NUMID
  AND CV.cv_ter_tipoid = TER.TIPOID
  AND CV.cv_ter_dvid = TER.DVID
  AND CV.cv_ccv_clave LIKE 'PROM%'

<The Problem Starts when I use the variable I gave to the function, if I give it to it in a normal query it works but not in an UDF>

  AND division = JCO.JCO_CON_SOP_OPE_DIV_NUMERO
  AND operadora = JCO.JCO_CON_SOP_OPE_NUMERO 
  AND sucursal = JCO.JCO_CON_SOP_NUMERO 
  AND contrato = JCO.JCO_CON_NUMERO 
                                                                                  
                  LIMIT 1

)
)
);`
```

Comment: Please get rid of the backquotes & prose that aren't part of your code & format your exact code in code blocks (via indent or fence). PS Debug questions require a [mre]. That includes an example we can cut & paste & run that you have already. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using queries `((Select ... ))` inside of a UDF is possible, but there are some limitations. The use of aggegation or window function and `limit` is only possible if during the start of the query all parameters are know. If, like in your case, the parameters of the UDF come from a table, then `limit` cannot be used.

Therefore, please remove the `limit` and add `any_value` to your query:

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(NOMTER) AS NOMBRE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the problem! You're a lifesaver!!!!